# algorithm-shorten +10 digits string

Tags: c#, algorithm, url-shortener

I'm using *C#* language for a project. I need to provide user with large (9+ digit) number, which they will have to reenter into another system (for later data correlation). Having a user enter a number that large (by hand) with no errors will be almost impossible.

I have been trying to come up with a solution to shorten that number using base64, but all the code I have found will create a string combination of character and digits. Is there a simple math algorithm I can use to make a large number smaller? The result should be numeric not alpha numeric.

Comment: How can you encode [0-9] into [0-9] and do so using fewer positions? Look into dashes for grouping and add a checksum number.

Comment: Yes you can.  It is called uuencode/uudecode.  It is used in unix operating system for tar packing (zip).  Since ASCII is 8 bits and a digit is 4 bits you can pack digits into 8 bits to get less characters.  uuenocode packs characters into only printable characters so ascii control characters are not used and character above 128 to 255 are not used.  Since uuencode is used in email standards it is in the library System.Web.Mail.MailEncoding.UUEncode

Comment: @jdweng _"The result should be **numeric** not alpha numeric"_

Comment: have you try to BCD convertion?   yournumber=> conver to byte => BCD you'll get shorter value.

Comment: Is what you are asking for possible without using letters? Using a simple example: provide a numeric representation of 778 using less numbers. Its not possible...you will run out of combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You address the problem in a wrong way, instead of changing the number size just build a convenient way for the user to copy past the number , a simple key event wich will copy the number to the buffer, then the user will not have to write the number down.

Comment: hi.unfortunately its not possible science the numbers are printed on images and these images are used to advertise our companies products in social networks

Answer (score 0):

Reducing a number using only numbers will never work.

What you really need is some form of error checking.
One that works very good is the Verhoeff Algorithm that will detect almost every typo. There are many examples to find online.

like:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15939/verhoeff-check-digit-in-c

Comment: the numbers are written by customers as a message via their cellphones.we do not want to force them to enter a complex text

Comment: No, the Verhoeff algorithm will only add one digit more, but will detect most common errors. Just try it and be amazed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hash algorithm to hash your large number, but you need to deal with hash collision.
One of those very easy to implement is checksum sum16:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

See sum16 you can only have 0-65536. Think about sum18 ?